# Not sure why it has to say not valid Json after replacing the values of paymentKey and Session key

Tags: java, api, rest, automation, rest-assured

I am trying to read a json file and  after traversing to attrib`s called "**paymentKey**" and "**Session key**" and changing their values through JSONObject , the post operation failing.

When i checked the out json after performing above changes it seems that structure is bit unordered , changed and even got to learn that json is not an valid one.

This is bit annoying and not sure how to keep the json format in tag after replacing the attrib`s values.

## Below is the Json used

```
{
    "idempotentId": "133215472229",
    "customerId": "12345",
    "brandId": "ANCHOR",
    "sellingChannel": "WEBOA",
    "items": [
        {
            "lineItemId": 123,
            "productId": "ANCHOR-WEBOA-640213214",
            "price": 1.19,
            "quantity": 1,
            "modifierGroups": [],
            "childItems": [],
            "note": " Drink without snacks"
        }
    ],
    "fulfillment": {
        "email": "12@gmail.com",
        "phoneNumber": "+912222621",
        "fulfillmentType": "PickUp",
        "asap": true,
        "pickupFirstName": "Kiran",
        "pickupLastName": "Kumar",
        "locationId": "33211111"
    },
    "payment": {
        "paymentKey": "12222-444-555-2222-44444121e",
        "sessionKey": "02f3waAjHJnVCTstOIu0jcSZfm_1HnGum1lZdsu6iDlLxxjO1FYsG9DHz9130ZzMMkjYY9j5w.7V8CijbmiPSo5ESDsq5hsQ.RpYSS5wkgoSSOMjktEyDTHZh1IPq0wNayp--DE3HE53uUgTEehCvHjSsUP5q8U2ZN1kZXbsufwm_mRCV8hLCrmWVTchhVUTJtmEpyYy142DtSp1ikXOVzGN5i9z_oP5e79QvgmU7_n1C5DeARFRagQClT87vUFBUfleSbLaRyH5v3wkU7ji9URUetcq1iAfS5-cNt6-uJaulFJc2y6uNdn0OtjIe74Hp5G7Gx54VYggduoqx5X1rsCssobfUSJUDLt_vVpz5BvhQM88EaysMAB6EcQHoOnZd_YWrz4IDAAZSwSBUFQAkypVmHo5pbvp64cTDrZE73EYkEwJLGf0dRmedMFe2HiU3DiCr97K3I3KuufxYM_eMRIcn739dntxTq4QePtFdqYGWBzXWQutvvqxWQPbNi7PG_-aauEOzlwJiXG94C8t7NGu0SjB8xHf11Z3orf5Ni4-fRKugY8VJNBl39hnb4-d-g47ut7iuiFDkDHJzlSgt9LFq__CxShG_.YkL2w7QEU85VHjpOj5urieCr4-G"
    },
    "subTotal": 100.19,
    "tax": 4.19
}
```

## Below is the snippet of the code

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;


public JSONObject constructCreateOrderPayload( String freedomPayPaymentKey,String orderInit_SessionKey, String payloadFile) {

String filepath  = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/test/resources/JsonFiles/"+payloadFile;

try {
            String jsonContents = new String((Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filepath))));
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonContents);
                        
            JSONObject payment_obj =  (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("payment");
            payment_obj.put("paymentKey", freedomPayPaymentKey);  
            payment_obj.put("sessionKey",orderInit_SessionKey);
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println( " After Changes in JSON OBJECT : ");
            System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
            
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            
            
        payload = jsonObject; //  when i print the json boject the format is displaced hence when validated it says invalid json 

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("No file found in the path ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
        return payload;
    }
```

**When I validated the Json after changes it shows as invalid with errors as shown in below snapshot**

[image]

I tried a lot but no success, can somebody please look in to issue and advise me where I am going wrong or provide an solution this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach was correct. The only mistake was i had not supply/pass on the correct values to few of the JSon attributes and that resulted in error response.

Rectified as per requirements and was able to get results correctly, hence closing this.

Answer (score 0):

JSON in unordered, When you print `jsonObject` before making the changes you will know the order of the JSON is changed, I have used the Jackson Databind libraries and below is a working code, Change it accordingly

```
    String filepath = "C:\\Users\\wilfred\\Desktop\\Input.json";

    try {
        String jsonContents = new String((Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filepath))));

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode expected = mapper.readTree(jsonContents);

        System.out.println("Before converting : " + expected.toString());

        JsonNode payment_obj = (expected.get("payment"));

        ((ObjectNode) payment_obj).put("paymentKey", "Trial1");
        ((ObjectNode) payment_obj).put("sessionKey", "Trial2");

        System.out.println("After converting : " + expected.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("No file found in the path ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes JSON is unordered. It was my mistake that i wrongly added few to values to few of the attributes hence forth i was not getting a successful response and i was thinking that changed JSON had issues due to which i was not getting the response. Anyways sorted my issue.